# Jump back from a delegate method to its caller

Tags: objective-c, delegates, mkmapview

Basically, I'm trying this:

- a) Call method A
- b) Method A calls method [locationManager startUpdatingLocation], which determines the current location
- c) Continue with method A, while using the determined current location

So (how) is it possible to jump back from startUpdatingLocation to method A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow you are describing would not work. As per the documents, [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] may take several seconds to return a value. You'd need to have the remaining code from method A, if it requires the location, added to the locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method which will be called when the locationManager gets a location.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Alright, I will put the remaining code of method A into [locationManager startUpdatingLocation].

Comment: It's the locationManager:didUpdateLocations, the call back from startUpdatingLocation :)